# Blazor wasm animate shapes to coordinates

Tags: animation, canvas, blazor

I have a blazor wasm application that receives once per second information about some devices that move around a cartesian coordinate system layout (X (mm), Y (mm), Angle, Speed (m/s), battery level (V), etc).
It shows informations in data grids ands tables but I would like to add a graphical visualization of the position.

In WPF I did that using a canvas control and scaling the coordinates to be displayed in the canvas:

**when the coordinates and/or angle (in degrees) changes, the position is updated to the new position**.

I would like to do the same in blazor but I don't know where to start.

**NOTE**: I am not seeking for code, just hints to which algorithm to use.

Comment: It sounds like you want to display some plots/charts.  Maybe one of these tools can help you:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChartJs.Blazor/, https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise

Answer (score 1):

- You can use a HTML5 Canvas element and draw to it, sort of like a WPF canvas. Most likely you would use an existing Blazor wrapper such as https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Canvas.
- You can also create an inline SVG using an <svg> element and adding your devices as sub-elements. I think it would have worse performance than the canvas if you are doing frequent updates, but it is an option.
- A third option is to have <div> with position:relative set and then adding your devices as <div>s or Blazor components inside it with position:absolute and then updating their top and left attributes to move them as needed. If your use case is simple enough, it is probably the most straightforward option.
- There are also several different charting and plotting libraries for Blazor, but I'm not familiar with them and they may not be suitable for rapidly changing data.